# wkhtmltopdf and pdfkit, "Segmentation fault (core dumped)", although working

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm using PDFKit to convert a webpage to a pdf file and save it in my computer. It works perfectly, but it also prints a message in the terminal, although it works:

```
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
```

The code that I'm using is:

```
kit = PDFKit.new("link_to_the_website", :page_size => 'A5')
file = kit.to_file("myfile.pdf")
```

The second line is the one that causes the error.

I know that PdfKit uses wkhtmltopdf, and I read that wkhtmltopdf has a problem when not in sudo mode, but I can't run my ruby code in sudo mode, and I do not know what to do to fix it. Can someone help me here please?

Links to the gems:

https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf
https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but I'll point to a recent [blog post](http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/12/05/12-gems-of-christmas-8-wicked_pdf/) worth reading when it comes to generating PDF from Ruby. wicked_pdf is used there, another wrapper for wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Thanks for the help. By the time, I fixed the pdfkit, but I want to try the wicked_pdf someday!

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem, following this installation of pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf:

http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2012/07/25/converting-html-to-pdf/